# What is the difference in the use of "von" and "des/der" as genitive?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Which construction is preferred in the following?

> 1. Bruder der jungen Frau
> 2. Bruder von junger Frau

Can someone please explain the particular constructions where "von" is preferred genitive over "des/der" and vice versa.

Comment: The most important difference is, that »Bruder von junger Frau« is wrong. It should be »Bruder von **der** junge**n** Frau«, and it is **not** genitive! It is dative.

Comment: @Hubert I don't think it's wrong, since it is used regularly in news headlines like _Bruder von junger Frau dreht sich im Kreis. Was dann passiert, ist absolut unglaublich_.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Klingt nach vice, und ist ein starkes Indiz *dafür*, dass es falsch ist.

Comment: "Bruder von junger Frau geschlagen" bedeutet, die Frau hat ihn geschlagen.

Comment: @userunknown meinst du grammatikalisch falsch oder inhaltlich falsch? Letzteres glaube ich gerne, ersteres nicht. Dann halt ein anderes Beispiel: _Mutter von fünf Kindern zu sein ist keine leichte Aufgabe_ – dieser Satz ist umgangssprachlich gebräuchlich und wesentlich häufiger anzutreffen als die _Mutter fünfer Kinder_.

Comment: @RolandIllig: Das ist auch nicht doppeldeutig. Mutter von 5 Kindern erschlagen wäre es wieder. Die Fragmente oben und mein Beispiel sind keine kompletten Sätze und daher schlecht zu analysieren. "Eine Mutter von 5 Kindern wurde erschlagen" vs. "Eine Mutter wurde von 5 Kindern erschlagen". "Bruder von junger Frau" oder "der jungen Frau" ist noch weniger als eine Überschrift im Telegrammstil.

Comment: @mub: Hast Du einen ganzen Satz, in dem diese Teilsätze vorkommen?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be confusing the genitive (spelling) case with the more general concept of describing a relationship or ownership.

[von](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/von_aus_ab_durch_per_seitens) requires the dative and would be used like this:

> [der] Bruder von der jungen Frau
>
> [der] Bruder von einer jungen Frau

It might be a little confusing that the definite article for female nouns takes the same form for both genitive and dative: *der* Frau.

Without the *von* you'd put the "junge Frau" into genitive:

> [der] Bruder der jungen Frau
>
> [der] Bruder einer jungen Frau

The option using dative is more colloquial and used in spoken language; the option with genitive is more formal and more appropriate for written language.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Genitive in formal language, also while speaking Standard German. In many German dialects, its usage has been limited or sometimes even non-existant. This idea that it does not exist in spoken language is false, especially when discussing complex topics (like at the university). However, I do not use it while speaking in my dialect.

Perhaps an analogy is best. If you are coming from the English speaking world, it's the same concept as this:

## Dative "m"

> The car **of the** man is red.

Das Auto/Der Wagen vom Mann ist rot.

## Genetive "s"

Do not let the apostrophe fool you. It was only added to English in non-emphasized syllables. The "s" is a remnant of inflection.

> The man'**s** car is red.

Das Auto de**s** Mann**es** ist rot.